# How to filter data within specific range in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter, amplitude

I tried to eliminate the spikes in Figure 1 by using `y = medfilt1(y)`.
What I get is as shown in Figure 2. The highest peaks are all equal to 1.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Now the problem is I want to get the highest peaks of 1.2 instead of 1. 
How do I solve it?

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve, what the wanted output is and why you are failing to do so, please read [ask] and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do you define a spike?

Comment: amplitude that more than 1.2.